# using find and replace for multiple string criteria in R

Tags: r, string, str-replace

I recently did a questionnaire and in the nationality field, I left an open text box field (a clear mistake).

Now that I have the results I am left with several strings that mean the same and I wonder if there is a function that would let me search and replace with somehow loose criteria.

I got a lot of french participants and got answers like Francaise, France, french or France from x territory, as an example. Is there any R function that would let me do the following (just partly naming the strings):

If data$nationality contains 'franc', 'frenc', then convert it to 'france'

Comment: You could do `data$nationality[grep("franc|frenc", tolower(data$nationality))] <- "france"`, or `data$nationality[grep("fr[a|e]nc", tolower(data$nationality))] <- "france"`

Comment: this is a simple en elegant answer that worked for me also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsub can do that:

```
df<-data.frame(strings=c("France","Francais","French"),stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

df$New_Strings<-gsub("Francais|French","France",df$strings)
```

the `|` operator acts like 'or', so you can string more of them in there if you like

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similarity measure to compute how close are the strings from the target strings `"Franc"` and `"Frenc"`. Then decide what to keep, based on a threshold value.

I will use package [`stringdist`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stringdist).

```
library(stringdist)

x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
I got a lot of french participants and got answers like francaise, france, french or france from x territory, as an example. Is there any R function that would let me do the following
')
pattern <- c('Franc', 'Frenc')
```

Now `sapply` function `stringsim` to each `pattern`, using two different measures, `"soundex"` and `"lw"`.

```
sim1 <- sapply(pattern, stringsim, x, method = 'soundex')
sim1 <- apply(sim1, 1, max)

sim2 <- sapply(pattern, stringsim, x, method = 'jw')
sim2 <- apply(sim2, 1, max)
```

Decide what to keep.

```
thresh <- 0.75

x[sim1 >= thresh]
#[1] "french"     "francaise," "france,"    "french"     "france"

x[sim2 >= thresh]
#[1] "french"  "france," "french"  "france"
```

The threshold can be made smaller.

```
thresh <- 0.70

x[sim1 >= thresh]
#[1] "french"     "francaise," "france,"    "french"     "france"

x[sim2 >= thresh]
#[1] "french"     "francaise," "france,"    "french"     "france"
```